# Why does this expression resolve to zero?

Tags: c++, expression

```
int a = 1/2 == 0.25 * 2;
```

I'm not sure why I'm not seeing this.  Am I missing something with precedence?

Comment: Think about the expression `1 / 2`. Both values are of type `int`, and the result will *also* be of type `int`.

Comment: Ah it's because the right will resolve to a double and the left an int.  I assumed both would be floored to 0 because the declared type was an int

Comment: `int a = ((1/2) == (0.25 * 2));` -> `int a = (0 == 0.5)` -> `int a = false;`

Comment: `1/2` is 0 since the result of integer division is truncated (rounded towards 0 or simply ignoring the part after the decimal), not floored. This is not equal to `0.25 * 2` which is equal to 0.5. Also, there is floating point error, which might cause comparisons like these to fail.

Comment: @FeiXang Truncation and rounding towards zero and ignoring the part after the decimal point and flooring are all the same thing, at least for positive numbers like these: and there is no floating point error here, as 0.25 is exact.

Answer (score 0):

Let digging:
`int a = 1/2 == 0.25 * 2;`

First, `1/2 == 0` (type of int), and `0.25 * 2 == 0.5` (type of double). So does `0` equal to `0.5`? No. So `a` receives the value of `0` (`FALSE`).